# Super key to pause, mute mic, and mute speakers in windows

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, mute

EDIT:Just rephrasing the question:

**Does anyone know how to mute the mic using autohotkey?**
Here's why I need it:

Whenever someone walks in my office I have to pause the media player. Sometimes, when I'm watching a video, I also have to mute the headphone speakers. And if I'm on a skype call I have to mute the mic.

I want to assign all those functions to a single hotkey for convienience (probably the "mute" or "play/pause" key) and I'm pretty sure autohotkey can do that, but I don't know how to mute the mic using autohotkey.

Plus, I also want to assign all reverse commands (play and unmute) to a single key (could be a different one or the same one).

(I don't think it matters, but I'm using windows 7)

Comment: you can pause all media programs using monitores ( with register PAUSE key option)

Comment: Rephrased the question for clarity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#z::
soundget, isMute, MICROPHONE, MUTE
if isMute = Off
    toMute = 1
else
    toMute=0
SoundSet, toMute, MICROPHONE, MUTE
return
```

Would toggle the mic's muted state on win&z. Muting master volume would be much the same, except instead of MICROPHONE you would put MASTER, however if it's just your media player you want muting it may be better to set up a hotkey to pause it, rather than mute system volume. Depending on the player it may be able to do it itself, otherwise look into the ControlSend function.

(This has the advantage of not using NirCMD, as while it's a brilliant tool, the ~.5 second disk lag is really annoying to me :()

Comment: I'd really like to do it without NirCMD, but the command above (as is) doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't report any errors when loading the script, but pressing the associated hotkey doesn't do anything either. I tried with both MICROPHONE and MASTER. I'll look into the help file and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Problem fixed: went to the Autohotkey insallation folder and set it to compatibility mode (WIN XP). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, awesome! That's something to remember :)

Comment: @Malabarba how do you set WIN XP compatibility?

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work for me. The mic is not muted. I have a realtek sound and am using the fromt jack.

Comment: this would be perfect, if we have a tray icon showing the mic status. Like MicMute.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend '[MicMute](http://sourceforge.net/projects/micmute/)' utility to mute or unmute the primary microphone using a keyboard. It has a nice taskbar icon, taskbar balloons, and auditory notifications you can modify.

What's awesomer it also let me select my keyboards extended media keys as a shortcut - I choose the button next to my system volume mute.

[image: MicMute Keyboard Muting of Windows Microphone]

Comment: Unfortunately, I've had bad luck with MicMute.  Something with it listening for a keyboard shortcut causes my entire system to come to a crawn when I type sometimes.  Closing MicMute immediately fixes the speed issues.

Comment: this is good, however, custom keyboard shortcut is restricted to pressing 2 keys. Eg. Ctrl+alt+m doesn't work. Might want to try TorkilsMicMuter if you desire this.

Answer (score 5):

A microphone muting utility:
http://oelgaard.dk/torkils/?TorkilsMicMuter

Shortcut key is configurable as is the signalling of the current mute state:

[image: Configuration]

Semitransparent corner notifications on all monitors of current mute state. If a corner notification is "in the way" during an online meeting, then the notification can easily be removed by hovering the mouse over it.
[image: Corner notifications]

Answer (score 4):

To extend Phoshi's answer, using `AutoHotkey` and this script can help (Ctrl+F8):

```
^F8::
SoundSet, +1, MICROPHONE, mute
return
```

In my case though, it was the following:

```
SoundSet, +1, MASTER, mute, 12
```

This might help to get exact audio device configuration: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SoundSet.htm#Ex

Answer (score 3):

you can do this and much more by using NirCMD along with AutoHotKey.

Take a look: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

> NirCmd is a small command-line utility
>   that allows you to do some useful
>   tasks without displaying any user
>   interface. By running NirCmd with
>   simple command-line option, you can
>   write and delete values and keys in
>   the Registry, write values into INI
>   file, dial to your internet account or
>   connect to a VPN network, restart
>   windows or shut down the computer,
>   create shortcut to a file, change the
>   created/modified date of a file,
>   change your display settings, turn off
>   your monitor, open the door of your
>   CD-ROM drive, and more...

Comment: Actually, it looks like it can mute any sound device with the "mutesysvolume" command. I'll test it now.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks!  
run nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 2 microphone

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

1. Go to your Skype
2. Select Tools
3. Select option
4. Click advance below
5. Then click Hotkeys
6. Check Enable keyboard shortcuts
7. Check mute microphone..and click it
8. Then select an additional key you want in muting the microphone.. like CTRL + Z... CTRL + D... any key  you want to choose
9. Finally, click Save..

Answer (score 1):

I have set ctrl+p to toggle the system sound, for window+z it would be:

`#z::Send {Volume_Mute}`

Comment: It will mute the speaker

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample `AutoHotKey` command to use `nircmd` to mute a mic. You will have to play around with the number at the end, it refers to mic number.

```
#z:: Run c:\tools\nircmd\nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 2 microphone 2
```

Press `Windows + Z` to toggle mute.