# Disable microphone for certain program

Tags: windows, windows-8, microphone

I don't want that certain program use my microphone. This isn't configuration in app to do it. Program use mic anyways.
So I wonder how to disable mic for it in windows? Any ideas? I use Windows 8.

UDP. It's two program which use my microphone. I need to block one.

UDP2. One of this program is Skype. I want that Skype work well. Another program use mic too, and my friends hear me twice. This is annoying, so i want block second program access to mic. I use simple microphone in my headset.

Comment: Can you select hardware device for program that is not supposed to have access to your microphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but simple answer is NO. In windows you cannot turn off or block microphone for specyfic program.

However you can try to workaround this:

1. Install some virtual audio device (Virtual Audio Cable or whatever that can appear as microphone in sound devices in Windows).
2. Set this virtual device as default communication device

   Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Sound(Manage Audio Devices) > Recording.

   Right click your virtual/fake device, and click "Set as default communication device". Hopefully your program will "listen" to that fake default device instead of microphone.
3. Skype will use it too by default, however in Skype you can go to configuration and set your real microphone manually.

If "default communication device" trick will not work - try to set virtual device as default recording device.

Answer (score -1):

Can you just disable your microphone in the Sound control panel while you use the program?

Right-click the Sound icon in the system tray, then choose Recording devices. Choose your microphone from the list and then click Properties. Finally, disable the device like this:[image: Disabling the microphone from Sound properties]

Comment: It's two programs use my microphone, that's a problem. I need block one.

Comment: Doesn't the microphone get locked to only one program at once? Try starting the program you want to use the microphone before the other.

Comment: Is either of the programs a "phone" type program?  There are specific settings for microphone use in phone programs vs others. Also, is this using the built-in mic? Also, is this applicable? - http://superuser.com/questions/55598/super-key-to-pause-mute-mic-and-mute-speakers-in-windows

Comment: One of this program is Skype. I want that Skype work well. Another program use mic too, and my friends hear me twice. This is annoying, so i want block second program access to mic. I use simple microphone in my headset.

Comment: Many programs have an option to select which mic to use or disable the mic. Skype does, and so should your other program.