# How can I change or disable the keyboard shortcut for unmuting one's microphone in BlueJeans?

Tags: windows, bluejeans

I use [BlueJeans](https://www.bluejeans.com/) for videoconference on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

How can I change or disable the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>M</kbd>) for unmuting one's microphone in BlueJeans?

I am aware of [Disable microphone for certain program](https://superuser.com/q/746603/116475) but I'm looking for a BlueJeans-specific solution.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.