# How I disable "one" desktop application to not use the microphone

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone, application-launch

Even after I go to the Setting>privacy>microphone, I am still unable to disable any of the "Desktop application" from using the mic.

I have tried searching for answers, everywhere it's suggesting me to switch off the apps that come from Microsoft App Store.

[Like these application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBeO0.jpg)

If there is a way to disable desktop applications, please help me.

FYI: I'm running on the latest Windows 10.

Thank you

Comment: There was a [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/746603/348859) for Win8. Have you tried that workaround? (Creating a fake microphone and pointing the desired apps to that one instead.)

Comment: Yes I have tried it, it's not helping me. There should be a way to not allow one desktop application to use the microphone. I don't know how though,